# invoke os.system as a non-root user in a root-user launched python program

Tags: python, linux

I want to run a python program using sudo (e.g. `sudo python test.py`) but within the python program when I use `os.system(<some command>)` to invoke other processes, I want to run them as a non-root user.

Is this doable?

Thanks!

Comment: Fork a subprocess. In the subprocess, call `os.setuid()` to the user, then do what you want. In the parent, wait for the subprocess to complete (`os.waitpid()`).

Comment: @alaniwi Thanks! This works! Another way I just found seems to be that I can add a prefix "sudo -u username" in front of the command I want to run to execute as that specific user.

Comment: Could you please add the solution you found as the right answer to the question. This might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
import os
import pwd

username = "nobody"

pwent = pwd.getpwnam(username)
uid = pwent.pw_uid
gid = pwent.pw_gid

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    # child

    # relinquish any privileged groups before we call setuid
    # (not bothering to load the target user's supplementary groups here)
    os.setgid(gid)
    os.setgroups([])

    # now relinquish root privs
    os.setuid(uid)

    # os.setuid should probably raise an exception if it fails,
    # but I'm paranoid so...
    if os.getuid() != uid:
        print("setuid failed - bailing")
        os._exit(1)

    return_value = os.system("id") // 256  # or whatever
    os._exit(return_value)

# parent
os.waitpid(pid, 0)

print("parent continues (still root here)")

os.system("id")
```

Gives:

```
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
parent continues (still root here)
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to add a prefix `sudo -u username` in front of the command one wants to run to execute as that specific user. For example, one can use `os.system('sudo -u user_a python test.py')` to run `test.py` inside a python script as `user_a`.